# Upgrade to Postgres 9.2 (incl. Hibernate) & Tomcat 7

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat6

We are planning an upgrade from PostgreSQL 8.2 to 9.2.4, and Tomcat from 6 to 7.

I have worked through various migration guide and want to ask you if you have any experience and whether there are any major changes (in the code, methods, etc.) or not.

Will I have to update the JDBC driver & Hibernate? Or should the migration work smoothly?

Is there anything I have to especially take care of? Any hints are welcome.

Comment: The complexity of the upgrade would for certain depend on your system, so a test migration is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: that is what I'm up to right now, i thought someone might have any experience with the migration, especially hibernate. The tomcat & postgres upgrade seems kinda easy - at least how it was shown inside the provided migration guides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the release notes for the products in question. The [PostgreSQL release notes are here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release.html) and you should at minimum read the upgrade and compatibility advice for each `.0` version (8.3.0, 8.4.0, 9.0.0, 9.1.0 and 9.2.0) to make sure you are prepared for any changes you may need to deal with. See the [version policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for guidance on why  you need to care about 8.2 to 8.3, etc.

In the case of PostgreSQL you absolutely *must* follow a proper upgrade process. The on-disk format database isn't compatible from 8.2 to 9.2. You must dump and reload, or use a more complex replication-based migration method using a 3rd party replication tool like Slony-I.

(PostgreSQL 8.4 and newer can be in-place upgraded using the `pg_upgrade` tool, but this isn't available for DBs as old as 8.2. A dump and reload is required from 8.2 to 8.4, so you can't just update to 8.4 then `pg_upgrade` to 9.2).

It is quite likely that you'll have to make query changes to any native queries in order to deal with things like the removal of the implicit `from`, `standard_conforming_strings`, etc.

It will be *vital* to update the JDBC driver, as the new driver understands `standard_conforming_strings`, the `hex` format for `bytea_output`, and most importantly it understands the updated and changed system catalog format. Don't try to use an old PgJDBC with a new server.

Similarly, updating Hibernate would be a very good idea, since the new Hibernate will have updates to its PostgreSQL dialect, updates for compatibility with Tomcat 7, etc etc.

I suggest doing this upgrade in stages.

- Upgrade PgJDBC
- Upgrade Hibernate
- Upgrade Tomcat
- Upgrate PostgreSQL

with testing between each stage. It'll take more work, but it'll keep you sane when you're trying to figure out what change broke something when.

Comment: @Mario I'm happy to help. You'll want to look into the Tomcat side, as I don't really know it.